# Making transparent maps for some projections in matplotlib basemap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I recently started using matplotlib's basemap. I want to create a transparent map with only borders, and this can be done with some basic projections like the miller projection in very simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure()

m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)

m.drawcoastlines(color = '0.5',linewidth=0.2)
m.drawmapboundary(color='0.5', linewidth=0.2)
m.drawcountries(color='0.5', linewidth=0.2)

plt.savefig('**my folder**\\worldmap.png', dpi=350, transparent = True)
```

This generates a map that is completely transparent except for country borders and continent borders

However, the problem arises when I do the same with another projection, like the robinson projection, by replacing the 'mill' in line 6 with 'robin'.
The resulting image has a white background instead of being transparent.

Can anyone help me with making other projections transparent as well? Or atleast confirm that there is no way to make some projections transparent?